# Exception while consuming data from kafka source in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-xd, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am getting kafka exception when tried kafka topic as source

Here is how i created stream

```
stream create --definition ":myDestination > log" --name ingest_from_broker
stream deploy ingest_from_broker --properties "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw"
```

When I am running it I am getting exception at log file

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 113
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:132) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeadersMessageConverter.java:105) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.extractMessageValues(AbstractBinder.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:698) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) [spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:69) [spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:63) [spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) [spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:43) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$AutoAcknowledgingChannelForwardingMessageListener.doOnMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:171) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.AbstractDecodingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractDecodingMessageListener.java:50) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4$1.doWithRetry(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:516) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276) [spring-retry-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:157) [spring-retry-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$4.onMessage(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:513) [spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:221) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.QueueingMessageListenerInvoker$KafkaMessageDispatchingSubscriber.onNext(QueueingMessageListenerInvoker.java:209) [spring-integration-kafka-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.util.RingBufferSubscriberUtils.route(RingBufferSubscriberUtils.java:67) [reactor-core-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor$BatchSignalProcessor.run(RingBufferProcessor.java:789) [reactor-core-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

I saw some threads where it is mentioned that setting up this property - 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw' will help but somehow this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either

```
stream create --definition ":myDestination > log --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw" --name ingest_from_broker
```

or

```
stream deploy ingest_from_broker --properties "apps.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw"
```

i.e. either the property must be specified on the application directly during Stream definition, or if supplied at deployment time, it must indicate what application does it apply to.